# How can I see which objects need repair?

Tags: far-cry-4

Some objects tell me to press E to repair it (with a blowtorch). 
Is there any indication if an object needs repair?

If I do such a repair, what is my benefit?

Comment: It should be noted that you can manually call the blowtorch, on my configuration it seems to default to Y. Repairing vehicles restores its health so it can suffer more crashes

Answer (score 2):

Well after a few more hours into Far Cry 4 I found out, that you only get rewarded for repairing armored trucks (the ones you have to protect while the golden path solidier is driving to the destination). So I'd suggest that you always repair those trucks after delivering them - get those extra bucks.
As far as repairing other things go, a repair sign only pops up when a vehicle is heavily damaged.

**Edit:** Sometimes you'll see a civilian vehicle standing alongside the road with a smoking hood. When you spot one of those, you can repair their vehicle and they'll give you some money in exchange.